# Custom cell too wide for tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've got a tableview with a custom cell in it. The cell renders with all the correct elements, but the width is way off.  The width of the cell seems to be three times as wide as it should be.

This is what I'm doing to specify which cell to use.  There's nothing too exciting here.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      tableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
}
```

and then later:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

I have no constraints on the tableviewcell that specify a minimum width for any element.

I've never had to to specify a tableviewcell width when using a custom tableviewcell.  I'm confused about how this is even happening.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?  Will I need to specify a width in the tableviewcontroller or is there another way to get the cell to be the correct width?

Comment: set clips to bounds to yes in your cell

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately, setting clipsToBounds to true has no effect when done inside the cell's awakeFromNib function or when done from the tableviewcontroller.

Comment: How do you pretend to dynamically auto-adjust dimensions without set minimal constraints in trailing or leading, programmatically or from xib/storyboard?

Comment: I don't know this is a correct solution. You have created your UITableviewCell in Nib, so there might be a possibility that you might have created the UITableviewCell in Any|Any Size class and now running it in iPhone. Give different backgroundcolor to your cell and check that in Preview.

Comment: I'm setting contrains on elements inside the xib, but the problem is the cell's width isn't being set to the width of it's parent/container.